# keras model with one connection per input node

Tags: keras, layer

I would like to create a sequential model in keras with one hidden layer with as many nodes as there are input nodes. Each input node should be connected to only one of the hidden nodes. All nodes in the hidden layer should be connected to a single output node: [as in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MA4cC.png)

I would like to be able to specify the activation function of the hidden layer.

Is it possible to achieve that with a Sequential() model in keras?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a custom layer where you can do everything you want:

```
import keras
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.layers import *
from keras import Sequential
import numpy as np

tf.set_random_seed(10)

class MyDenseLayer(keras.layers.Layer):
  def __init__(self):
    super(MyDenseLayer, self).__init__()

  def parametric_relu(self, _x):
    # some more or less complicated activation
    # with own weight
    pos = tf.nn.relu(_x)
    neg = self.alphas * (_x - abs(_x)) * 0.5
    return pos + neg

  def build(self, input_shape):
    # main weight
    self.kernel = self.add_weight("kernel",
                                  shape=[int(input_shape[-1]),],
                                  initializer=tf.random_normal_initializer())
    # any additional weights here
    self.alphas = self.add_weight('alpha', shape=[int(input_shape[-1]),],
                        initializer=tf.constant_initializer(0.0),
                            dtype=tf.float32)
    self.size = int(input_shape[-1])

  def call(self, input):
    linear = tf.matmul(input, self.kernel*tf.eye(self.size))
    nonlinear = self.parametric_relu(linear)
    return nonlinear


model = Sequential()
model.add(MyDenseLayer())
model.build((None, 4))

print(model.summary())
x = np.ones((5,4))
print(model.predict(x))
```